# Call a Postgres function that returns a record, passing in the result of a query

Tags: sql, function, postgresql, plpgsql, postgresql-9.3

The problem is that I need to run a query (only known at run-time) to determine the input parameter to my function, which needs to return a result.  For example, I want to write:

```
CREATE FUNCTION foo(inputKey INT) RETURNS TABLE (c0 INT, c1 TEXT) AS $$
    BEGIN
        -- Do something with inputKey to compute and return result
    END;
$$ LANGUAGE PLPGSQL;
```

These are the queries I have tried to date:

```
-- Doesn't even run (exception)
SELECT * FROM foo(SELECT foreignKey FROM someTable WHERE primaryKey = 5);

-- Runs, but returns a single column with all columns listed in it's value
SELECT foo(foreignKey) FROM someTable WHERE primaryKey = 5;

-- Same problem as previous
SELECT * FROM (SELECT foo(foreignKey) FROM someTable WHERE primaryKey = 5) AS a
```

I have also tried changing the result type to

- `myType (CREATE TYPE myType AS (c0 INT, c1 TEXT))`
- `SETOF myType`
- `RECORD`
- `SETOF RECORD`

All of the above exhibit the same behavior.

What is the syntax to get a multi-column result from calling a plpgsql function that returns a record, table, or setof records? This problem sounds really simple, but I have been unable to figure out the syntax for this after numerous internet searches. All of the questions I have found online use of the syntax `SELECT * FROM function()`, with absolutely no examples of someone passing an input parameter from another query.

Comment: What about `SELECT foo(foreignKey).* FROM someTable WHERE primaryKey = 5;`? This probably will unnests record into columns ([SQLFiddle example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/d8616/3))

Comment: @TomasGreif :  The syntax for that is SELECT (foo(foreignKey)).* FROM someTable WHERE primaryKey = 5;  Unfortunately, this will result in the funtion being invoked for every column in the return table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You almost got there:

`SELECT * FROM foo((SELECT foreignKey FROM someTable WHERE primaryKey = 5));`

Note the extra set of parenthesis to create a sub-query.  The return values will be used as function parameters.

The results will be expanded after the function is called.

Answer (score 5):

> What is the syntax to get a multi-column result from calling a plpgsql
>   function that returns a record, table, or setof records?

That's actually two or three different questions.

- `table` and `setof record` are closely related ("table" implies a well defined row type, while records can be well defined or anonymous, requiring different treatment).
  [@Kirk provided a solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24067721/939860) for a *table* function.
- Functions returning a *single record* are a different case. Those allow more ways to call them. Like:

  ```
  SELECT foo(foreignkey).*  -- decomposing is simple for well-known types
  FROM   sometable
  WHERE  primarykey = 5;
  ```

The Postgres query planner has a weak spot there and evaluates the function multiple times this way. In Postgres 9.3 use a `LATERAL` join instead for expensive functions returning multiple columns:

```
    SELECT f.*
    FROM   sometable s
    LEFT   JOIN LATERAL foo(s.foreignkey) f ON true
    WHERE  s.primarykey = 5;
```

Details:

- [Record returned from function has columns concatenated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25392371/record-returned-from-function-has-columns-concatenated?lq=1)

Comment: 'tis true.  I provided the answer that I thought the OP was hinting at.