# RAILS SQL Subquery optimization

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, crosstab, find-by-sql, aggregate-filter

I have a query which looks like this:

```
@inventory =  Pack.find_by_sql("SELECT Packs.id, "+
" (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Stocks WHERE (Stocks.pack_id = Packs.id AND Stocks.status = 'online'      AND Stocks.user_id = #{current_user.id})) AS online,"+
" (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Stocks WHERE (Stocks.pack_id = Packs.id AND Stocks.status = 'offline'     AND Stocks.user_id = #{current_user.id})) AS offline,"+
" (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Stocks WHERE (Stocks.pack_id = Packs.id AND Stocks.status = 'depositing'  AND Stocks.user_id = #{current_user.id})) AS depositing,"+
" (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Stocks WHERE (Stocks.pack_id = Packs.id AND Stocks.status = 'withdrawing' AND Stocks.user_id = #{current_user.id})) AS withdrawing,"+
" (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Stocks WHERE (Stocks.pack_id = Packs.id AND Stocks.status = 'selling'     AND Stocks.user_id = #{current_user.id})) AS selling,"+
" (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Transactions WHERE (Transactions.pack_id = Packs.id AND Transactions.status = 'buying' AND Transactions.buyer_id = #{current_user.id})) AS buying"+
" FROM Packs WHERE disabled = false")
```

I am thinking there's a way to make a new sub-query so that instead of

```
SELECT FROM Stocks
```

the query selects from a stored table

```
SELECT FROM (Stocks WHERE (Stocks.pack_id = Packs.id AND Stocks.user_id = #{current_user.id}))
```

which would only be queried *once*. Then the `WHERE Stocks.status = ?` stuff would be applied to that stored table.

Any help guys?

Comment: Please always provide your version of Postgres.

Comment: 9.1 at the moment. I will probably be updating to 9.4 at some point.

Comment: [So do you have your answer?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/169168)

Answer (score 2):

The best query depends on data distribution and other details.

This is very efficient as long as most `pack_id` from the subqueries are actually used in the join to `packs` (most `packs` are `NOT disabled`):

```
SELECT p.id
     , s.online, s.offline, s.depositing, s.withdrawing, s.selling, t.buying
FROM   packs p
LEFT   JOIN (
   SELECT pack_id 
        , count(status = 'online'      OR NULL) AS online
        , count(status = 'offline'     OR NULL) AS offline
        , count(status = 'depositing'  OR NULL) AS depositing
        , count(status = 'withdrawing' OR NULL) AS withdrawing
        , count(status = 'selling'     OR NULL) AS selling
   FROM   stocks
   WHERE  user_id = #{current_user.id}
   AND    status = ANY('{online,offline,depositing,withdrawing,selling}'::text[])
   GROUP  BY 1
   ) s ON s.pack_id = p.id 
LEFT   JOIN (
   SELECT pack_id, count(*) AS buying
   FROM   transactions
   WHERE  status = 'buying'
   AND    buyer_id = #{current_user.id}
   ) t ON  t.pack_id = p.id
WHERE  NOT p.disabled;
```

In pg **9.4** you can use the **aggregate FILTER clause**:

```
SELECT pack_id 
     , count(*) FILTER (WHERE status = 'online')      AS online
     , count(*) FILTER (WHERE status = 'offline')     AS offline
     , count(*) FILTER (WHERE status = 'depositing')  AS depositing
     , count(*) FILTER (WHERE status = 'withdrawing') AS withdrawing
     , count(*) FILTER (WHERE status = 'selling')     AS selling
FROM   stocks
WHERE  ...
```

Details:

- [How can I simplify this game statistics query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27136251/how-can-i-simplify-this-game-statistics-query/27141193#27141193)

Use **`crosstab()`** for the pivot table to make that faster, yet:

```
SELECT p.id
     , s.online, s.offline, s.depositing, s.withdrawing, s.selling, t.buying
FROM   packs p
LEFT   JOIN  crosstab(
   $$
   SELECT pack_id, status, count(*)::int AS ct
   FROM   stocks
   WHERE  user_id = $$ || #{current_user.id} || $$
   AND    status = ANY('{online,offline,depositing,withdrawing,selling}'::text[])
   GROUP  BY 1, 2
   ORDER  BY 1, 2
   $$
  ,$$SELECT unnest('{online,offline,depositing,withdrawing,selling}'::text[])$$
    ) s (pack_id int
      , online int
      , offline int
      , depositing int
      , withdrawing int
      , selling int
       ) USING (pack_id)
LEFT   JOIN (
   SELECT pack_id, count(*) AS buying
   FROM   transactions
   WHERE  status = 'buying'
   AND    buyer_id = #{current_user.id}
   ) t ON  t.pack_id = p.id
WHERE  NOT p.disabled;
```

Details here:

- [PostgreSQL Crosstab Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3002499/postgresql-crosstab-query/11751905#11751905)

If most `packs` are `disabled`, `LATERAL` joins will be faster (requires pg **9.3** or later):

```
SELECT p.id
     , s.online, s.offline, s.depositing, s.withdrawing, s.selling, t.buying
FROM   packs p
LEFT   JOIN LATERAL (
   SELECT pack_id 
        , count(status = 'online'      OR NULL) AS online
        , count(status = 'offline'     OR NULL) AS offline
        , count(status = 'depositing'  OR NULL) AS depositing
        , count(status = 'withdrawing' OR NULL) AS withdrawing
        , count(status = 'selling'     OR NULL) AS selling
   FROM   stocks
   WHERE  user_id = #{current_user.id}
   AND    status = ANY('{online,offline,depositing,withdrawing,selling}'::text[])
   AND   pack_id = p.id
   GROUP  BY 1
   ) s ON TRUE
LEFT   JOIN LATERAL (
   SELECT pack_id, count(*) AS buying
   FROM   transactions
   WHERE  status = 'buying'
   AND    buyer_id = #{current_user.id}
   AND   pack_id = p.id
   ) t ON TRUE
WHERE  NOT p.disabled;
```

Why `LATERAL`? And are there alternatives in pg **9.1**?

- [Record returned from function has columns concatenated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25392371/record-returned-from-function-in-query-has-columns-concatenated-in-postgresql/25392910#25392910)

Comment: This code works, and is what I'm generally trying to do, but is about 15 times slower. I am not using enough test data though, so I will have to add more and compare.

Comment: @user1694853: For performance optimization we'd need more data. Especially table definitions, cardinalities and value frequencies (what percentage of `pack` is `disabled`, how many different values in `stocks.status`? Freuquecies? Etc. I added some more options.

Comment: Holy crap you have an insane knowledge of sql. Im gonna have to do some reading to understand whats going on here, lol. Thanks for the help. I will get back to you when I've tested against a larger object pool.

Comment: I think I should upgrade to pg 9.4. Is 9.5 out yet or just their documentation?

Comment: @AronGreenspan: 9.5 is the new devel version. [9.4 is rc now.](http://www.postgresql.org/about/news/1555/) Wait with the upgrade until it's released.

Answer (score 0):

If what you're after is a count of the various types, something like the following would be much less code and easier to read/maintain, IMO...

You could split them up into the different tables, so, for `stocks`, something like this:

```
@inventory = Pack.find_by_sql("SELECT status, count(*)
                               FROM stocks
                               WHERE user_id = ?
                               GROUP BY status
                               ORDER BY status", current_user.id)
```

Note the importance of using `?` to prevent *SQL injection*. Also, *Ruby* supports multiline strings, so there's no need to quote and concatenate every line.

You can do something similar for the other tables.