# Remove rows that are within 15 minutes from the very first row that meets the criteria

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, window-functions, group-by

I have data that looks like this

```
Name     |  Date                     |  Event     |  Event_ID
_____________________________________________________________
BRADLEY  |  2014-12-01 16:15:26.442  |  ACCESSED  |  268766  
BRADLEY  |  2014-12-01 16:15:36.794  |  ACCESSED  |  268766  
BRADLEY  |  2014-12-01 16:15:50.618  |  DENIED    |  268766  
BRADLEY  |  2014-12-01 16:16:04.89   |  DENIED    |  268766  
BRADLEY  |  2014-12-01 16:18:01.036  |  DENIED    |  268766  
BRADLEY  |  2014-12-01 16:18:31.335  |  DENIED    |  268766  
CHARLES  |  2014-12-01 08:33:34.831  |  ACCESSED  |  445317  
CHARLES  |  2014-12-01 08:33:44.041  |  ACCESSED  |  445317  
CHARLES  |  2014-12-01 14:56:49.872  |  ACCESSED  |  10333360
CHARLES  |  2014-12-01 14:56:57.549  |  ACCESSED  |  10333360
CHARLES  |  2014-12-01 14:56:59.248  |  ACCESSED  |  10333360
CHARLES  |  2014-12-01 14:56:62.221  |  ACCESSED  |  10333360
CHARLES  |  2014-12-01 14:56:63.226  |  ACCESSED  |  10333360
```

My requirement is that I need to remove events that are `ACCESSED` that are within 15 minutes apart. For example BRADLEY, I would remove the second accessed at timestamp `16:15:36.794`. That part is easy for me as I can just logically join the same table together comparing current row to next row and do logic on the `Date`.

Now the issue I'm coming across is CHARLES. His `Event_ID` of `10333360` is a bit more complicated than BRADLEY's use case. For CHARLES, I will need to remove all `ACCESSED` with `Event_ID` of `10333360` except the one with `Date` of `14:56:49.872`. That's because I need to remove all dates that are within 15 minutes at the start of a new `Event_ID`. The real world issue is that there are too much "duplicates" when a user is `ACCESSED` and I'm doing data cleanup to remove all these unnecessary `ACCESSED` data.

I thought about using window functions in Postgres but there doesn't seem to be anything that can help me with the logic in comparing the dates (http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-window.html)

I do have some ideas on how to tackle this problem using stored procedures and create temp tables so that I can actually use variables in a Java-like way. But of course I want it to be efficient and I'm hoping to learn new techniques on how to tackle a problem like this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is tricky, because which rows are deleted and which rows stay depend on the rest of the table. So you have a **moving target**. To *pin the chicken down*, I suggest you apply a grid (of 15 minutes in your case):

```
SELECT tbl_id, row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY grid_start, event_id, name
                                  ORDER BY date) rn
FROM  (
   SELECT g AS grid_start, g + interval '15 min' AS grid_end
   FROM  (SELECT min(date) AS mind, max(date) AS maxd
          FROM   tbl
          WHERE  event = 'ACCESSED') t
        , generate_series(t.mind, t.maxd, interval '15 min') g
   ) g
JOIN   tbl t ON t.date >= g.grid_start
            AND t.date <  g.grid_end
WHERE  event = 'ACCESSED';
```

The implicit `LATERAL` join requires Postgres **9.3**+.

- [Record returned from function has columns concatenated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25392371/record-returned-from-function-has-columns-concatenated/25392910#25392910)

To substitute in older versions:

```
   FROM  (SELECT generate_series(min(date)
                               , max(date)
                               , interval '15 min') g
          FROM tbl WHERE event = 'ACCESSED') g
```

Now it's simple to `DELETE`:

```
DELETE FROM tbl t
USING (<above query>) x
WHERE  t.tbl_id = x.tbl_id
AND    x.rn > 1;
```

Only the first row per name in every 15 min interval survives.
Note that you can still have *two* rows within 15 minutes (neighboring grid cells), but never three. Or generally speaking: never more than *n+1* rows per *n* consecutive intervals.

If that's not good enough I suggest a **procedural** solution. Iterate through qualifying rows, remember the `date` of the first survivor and then return the id (for deletion) of every following row until the date is > 15 minutes later. Remember the date of that next survivor etc. Similar to:

- [GROUP BY and aggregate sequential numeric values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8014577/group-by-and-aggregate-sequential-numeric-values/8014694#8014694)

Aside: don't call a `timestamp` "date", that's misleading.

Comment: Wow, this is some kind of a solution. Currently testing it but one problem, is there a syntax error at 'generate_series(mind, maxd, interval '15 min') g'?

Comment: @cYn: You need Postgres 9.3 or later. since you did not specify I naturally assumed the *current* the version of Postgres.

Comment: Ahh wait, never mind. That generate_series is being joined with the nested selected statement above it. The two 'g' alias got me confused for a bit.

Comment: @cYn: I added the missing event_id for the PARTITION and a variant for older versions without LATERAL.

Comment: Simply amazing. Your code works. Now I just need to comb it through so I can understand it and throw it in my tool box. Thank you for this.